# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification gradle error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I keep receiving an error: `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0`

This error shows on `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` line.

I added Firebase to my app and it shows that these dependencies can be updated to newer versions.

***I know about other same questions but `appcompat` and Firebase versions are different.***

Here is the code in *app/build.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.airliner.chatting"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Just copy the second library name from the error message, add it to `dependencies` and change it's version to the same as the first library name.